# How do I reset data from STDIN when I am finished with it?

Tags: perl, stdin

I have a program while gets data from a pipe of the contents of a test file (`cat file`). I typically use the diamond operator to get the data line by line from STDIN, till the last line. Trouble is that I would like to reuse the same data for more than one subroutine. How is it possible to reset reading of STDIN so that the data can be read again from the first line?

```
sub downloadsrt {
    print "Printing list of subtitle files in downloadable form..\n";
    while (<>) {
        chomp($_);
        (my $fname,my $path, my $suffix) = fileparse($_);
        $_=$fname;
        my ($name, $ext) = $fname =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/;  
        #For srt
        my $newfile=$path.$name.".$ext";
        $newfile =~ s/\s/%20/g; 
        $newfile =~ s/\/root/http:\/\/$localip/;
        print $newfile."\n";
    }
}
sub dummysub {
    while (<>) {
        // Something else
    }
}

downloadsrt;
dummysub;
```

I would like to access STDIN using multiple subroutines, and each should get data from the first line of STDIN.

Unless I am mistaken this is not lexically scoped.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You can however store content in array, or run your logic in parallel, for each line read from STDIN.

Comment: [`IO::Mux`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Mux), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @mpapec, you need to store the data from STDIN into an array:

```
my @stdin = <>;
mysub_1(\@stdin);
mysub_2(\@stdin);
```

Comment: How can I check whether `<>` holds any data, before assigning it to an array? Otherwise, the first command here, waits for data.

Comment: `<>` is not a data structure but an I/O operator, so it doesn't hold any data. Considering you get your data from a `cat` command it shouldn't be a problem as you always get the EOT (end of transmission) character.